# how to access value of object using useState hook in reack

Tags: reactjs, api, object, react-hooks, use-state

This is api of movie which contain movie as key and movies detail as object
Now I have get the values of movie in useState but I not able to figure out how exactly I can get the details

```
{ 
"movies": [
{
        "Name":"The Forever Purge",
        "releasedate":"27 aug 2012",
        "id": 1,
        "genre" :"Action/Horror/Thriller", 
        "imageUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sisX7wQf6owcj3qys413l471bNu5iM0T/view? 
                     usp=sharing"
    },
    {
        "Name":"Reminiscence",
        "releasedate":"27 aug 2012",
        "id": 2,
        "genre" :"Mystery/Romantic/Sci-Fi", 
         "imageUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GBzbZ6VC243-1kg4EsaYwq6Qm9fLDdJb/view? 
                      usp=sharing"
    }
]
}
```

this is currently I am writing in code
But this is not getting we the details of movie

```
const [moviesList, setMoviesList] = useState({});

  const getMovies = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://run.mocky.io/v3/55492543-1c03-4b5e-8ff4-28bbd2638780"
    );
    var data= await response.json();
    setMoviesList(data);
    // console.log("hiii");
  };

  useEffect =(() => {
      getMovies();
    },
    []);
```

so can any one please help me

Comment: Are you trying to .map your moviesList.movies and it does not get displayed or are you trying console.log your moviesList right after you set your state?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running `getMovies` for one time, it is better for you to define that function inside `useEffect` and call it there:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getMovies = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('...');
    const data = await response.json();
    setMovieList(data);
  }
  getMovies();
}, []);
```

This is what recommended by official documentation, for more information:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/